# How to use "what kind of"

Tags: word-usage

If I look at a book about vehicles, can I say “What kind of vehicle is it?" to get the answer “It’s a bike." (or a truck, a car, a motorcycle, etc)? Is that question correct or not? How should I ask?

Answer (score 1):

*What kind of vehicle is it?* is grammatical, but it might, depending on the circumstances, be more appropriate to say *What kind of vehicle is that?*

Comment: thank you. How about" what is it? "it is more appropriate to say "what is that? or what is this?" than " what is it?. Right?

Comment: @Kid123: Impossible to answer a question like that in isolation, and certainly not in a comment. It depends on the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - that is a correct way to ask your question.

You could also ask:

- what sort of...
- what type of...

These are all functionally equivalent ways of asking the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much every one and Can I ask "What kind of vehicle are they/those/these?" to get the answer “they are bikes." and how about "what kinds of" when can I use it?

Comment: Yes, you might ask "What kinds of vehicles do you offer?"

Answer (score 0):

You could also say, 'which type of vehicle is a Jeep Grand Cherokee?'  Answer might be: Midsized SUV

But then you would need a list available for them to pick from.

Comment: Can I say "which type of vehicle is a Toyota? To get answer "Sedan"